# Windows Server 2012 R2: File and Storage Services - Must a User be logged on for service continuity?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm running File and Storage Services on Windows Server 2012 R2. I need to run gpupdate /force, and so need to logoff. I want to be sure that upon logging off (there's only one user ever logged on, and the user doesn't get logged off other than at reboots) my shares will still be available to domain users. I've tried finding a documented answer, but I think it's probably such an obvious answer that I can't find it written anywhere. Please forgive my mediocre Google-Fu skills.

So, if you logoff as the only logged on user, are File and Storage Services (not to mention ADDS, DNS and other services) continually provided?

After rebooting this host, do these services automatically start and become available to domain computers? Or do you need to logon for the server to begin providing these services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to have a user logged on at all for any of those services to keep running. They should all start automatically when the server boots. If you go into the Services node in Computer Management or the Services MMC snap-in, you'll see those services listed with a startup type of "Automatic". That means they run when the server boots.

You should definitely make sure everything is configured correctly and the server has at least one static IP address before rebooting.

Comment: All correctly configured, server has a static. Thanks a lot for your answer, I always thought "Automatic" meant they automatically run at logon.